# why are the routes undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to run any (and all) of the React-Router examples https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples on my local machine while only changing ES6 syntax to ES5 I keep getting the same error arising from the same line of code

Code

```
 Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
```

Error

```
Cannot read property 'validateProps' of undefined
```

I'm not changing anything about the examples except that instead of using ES6 to declare the dependencies and deconstruct Router

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;
```

I included links to the js files in my index and did this for the Router

```
var Route = Router[0];
var RouteHandler = Router[1];
var Link = Router[2];
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/2630/) is a jsfiddle with ES5 version of the code that's pasted [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rackt/react-router/master/examples/shared-root/app.js) from github

Here's the full code with ES5/6 changes that I'm trying to get to work

```
var Route = Router[0];
    var RouteHandler = Router[1];
    var Link = Router[2];

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ol>
          <li><Link to="home">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="signin">Sign in</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="forgot-password">Forgot Password</Link></li>
        </ol>
        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SignedIn = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Signed In</h2>
        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Home = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <h3>Welcome home!</h3>
    );
  }
});

var SignedOut = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Signed Out</h2>
        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SignIn = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <h3>Please sign in.</h3>
    );
  }
});

var ForgotPassword = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <h3>Forgot your password?</h3>
    );
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route handler={SignedOut}>
      <Route name="signin" handler={SignIn}/>
      <Route name="forgot-password" handler={ForgotPassword}/>
    </Route>
    <Route handler={SignedIn}>
      <Route name="home" handler={Home}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('example'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

`var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;` essentially mean:

```
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Link = Router.Link;
```

Your approach:

```
var Router = ReactRouter;
var Route = Router[0];
var RouteHandler = Router[1];
var Link = Router[2];
```

doesn't quite work since Router is a object (type `ReactRouter` into the console and you'll see the object and its methods/properties), not an array, so you can't use bracket indexes.

Working example with your code: http://jsbin.com/wotefobuji/1/edit?html,js,output